# Specialized django query

Tags: python, django, django-models

As you can guess from the title, I'm not exactly sure how to describe what I want. Please take a look at the following classes:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as Auth_User


class User(Auth_User):

    Portfolio = models.ManyToManyField('PortfolioItem', through='SkillTag')
    Age = models.IntegerField(blank=False)

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.full_name


class PortfolioItem(models.Model):

    Title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)


class SkillTag(models.Model):

    User = models.ForeignKey('User')
    PortfolioItem = models.ForeignKey('PortfolioItem')

    Tag_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
```

What I need to do, is for every user, get all the `Tag_Name` values of it's `SkillTags`, how do I do this?

Comment: What's the difference between what you want and something simple like  SkillTag.objects.all() or SkillTag.objects.values('Tag_Name')?  Showing us some examples of how what you've tried is wrong or does not match what you want might help in finding a solution.

Comment: do you want it per user ? I mean get all `Tag_Name` for a given `user` instance ?

Comment: @karthikr: Yes, I want it per user. Get all tag names for a given user instance. Preferably as a function inside `User`

Comment: SkillTag.objects.filter(user=myuser) will give you all the SkillTags for a given user 'myuser'.  If you have a bunch of users you could do filter(user__in=users)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
class User(Auth_User):
    #other attributes
    def tag_names(self):
        return self.skilltag_set.values_list('Tag_Name', flat=True)
```

So, here, we are doing a couple of things:

- [Querying in reverse ForeignKey relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

Since you are not using a `related_name` in the ForeignKey attribute, by default django would assign the model name (lowercase) followed by `_set` attribute, which makes it `.skilltag_set.all()`

- [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

Returns a ValuesQuerySet — a QuerySet subclass that returns tuples when used as an iterable, rather than model-instance objects.

Example: `[('a'), ('b'), ('c')]`

Basically, you are retriving an iterable of `ValuesQuerySet` (think of it as a list or any other iterables) consisting of tuples.

- flat=True

This basically flattens the on-tuples into single values.

Example: `['a', 'b', 'c']`

Comment: Would you be so king as to explain the part `values_list('Tag_Name', flat=True)`. Especially `flat=True`?

Comment: I'd add a _distinct()_ at the end maybe. Depends on your needs.

Answer (score 3):

most obvious: using the [reverse relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) of ForeignKey fields:

```
def skill_names_1(user):
  return [t.name for t in user.skilltag_set.all()]
```

The same thing, but explicitly selecting for the user.  also, it fetches only the required field from the database.

```
def skill_names_2(user):
  return SkillTag.objects.filter(User=user).values_list('Tag_Name',flat=True)
```

Either of these can also work as a method of User.  Of course, typically the argument would be called `self` instead of `user`.

All the skills for a group of users:

```
def skill_names_3(users):
  return SkillTag.objects.filter(User__in=users).values_list('Tag_Name',flat=True)
```

Comment: Dayyum, you're good at this. How long have you been using django, sir?